# rails 3.2.x to rails 4.2 upgrade : HTTP_COOKIE issue in request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, request, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I recently upgraded `rails` from `3.2 to 4.2.10` and I uses `cookie store` for storing the session. Now, the request which comes from other apps to my app server `request` object didn't have `HTTP_COOKIE` which I set from my app.
I checked `Rack::Request` class but can't find anything relevant. Without that I am not able to authorize request. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi can you share your investigation?

Comment: actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb, railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb, activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb, actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb

Comment: reverted above files to use old way

Comment: @SachinR - Try the below solution and let me know

Comment: See if you can create socat debug tunnel to view the traffic http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Answer (score 2):

According to [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L178) in source code, `secret_key_base` needs to be set; otherwise `LegacyKeyGenerator` will be used. It's sufficient to create `config/secrets.yml`, with something similar for every environment:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 07e4bd41e6a5d2da57a8b1b8fd0ac92bf58c90d83da67731e3cd50226ef5a129e7ff568bf080d7c7462d36e5012d252053dd05e6c6509f6ed82c13744186e227
```

And also [Upgrading page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#cookies-serializer) recommends setting `cookie_serializer` to `hybrid` option to incrementally migrate legacy cookies:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```